# Read Post data from a popout page

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am a newbie to php and am working on a project.

I have a button on one page which opens up a pop out page for some user input.

how do i pass the data on the popout page to the parent page once the user clicks the submit button on the popout page?

Is there any javascript that i will have to use or this could be done with the help of a php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a new window when you say popup, you can get/setthe opener's elements from your popup like this:
window.opener.document.getElementById("your element").value = "new value";

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what i wanted... can you also help me with some code... i am really new to javascript! :(

Comment: @Guns sure man..always glad to help..You said my answer was what you needed, would you mind marking my answer as accepted then?

Answer (score 2):

Ok , you can give us some code to start with, but the popup page will be a form and when the user will press ok ( for example) the method will be post\get with action to the parent page you need, and this is how you will pass the var!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use AJAX, which is a bit more advanced, especially if you're new to programming. A more simple approach is using a HTML-form with POST/GET, targetting your PHP-script.

Consider:

```
// form.html
<form action="myScript.php" action="POST">
   <input type="text" name="username" />
</form>

// myScript.php
<?php

// Check if the user tried to pass data to the script
if( isset($_POST['username']) ) {
   echo "Hello, your username is: " . $_POST['username'];
}

?>
```

W3Schools has a bit more detailed tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp). If you're going with this approach, you need to sanitize user input to prevent SQL-injection and XSS.

Comment: great! but how can i exchange the $_POST data between two windows?

Comment: Either by a hidden `<input>` element, or preferably by using `$_SESSION`: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Oh! ok... so for getting the session variable work on the existing parent page, i will have to refresh the page. or could that also be done via a javascript?

Comment: You can do that via javascript: `location.reload();` :-)